# Наложение цветов, C#

Tags: c#, цвета

У меня есть два изображения - А и Б, которые я хотел бы сложить.

Причем они должны складываться таким образом, чтобы получилось как "слои" в фотошопе/паинтнете - то есть изображение А позади изображения Б.

Беда в том, что в изображении Б используется прозрачность.

Как следствие пиксель должен трансформировать по какой то формуле, но я не смог вычислить самостоятельно как именно.

Если у изображения Б пиксель прозрачен, то мы юзаем пиксель А

Если у изображения Б пиксель сплошной, то мы юзаем пиксель Б

А как мы получаем пиксель например с половиной прозрачности?

Comment: Цвет кодируется как `AARRGGBB`, где байт `AA` — это альфа-канал. `255` это полностью непрозрачный, `0` — полностью прозрачный.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB

Comment: офигеть ты помог

Comment: Ок, если вы знаете где взять альфу, то в чем проблема-то?

Comment: я не знал как сложить R G B с использованием альфы, чтобы получить корректный цвет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему бы не так: если alpha — прозрачность пикселя верхней картинки, то результирующий пиксель есть средневзвешенное пикселя верхней картинки с весом `alpha`, и нижней с весом `(1 - alpha)`?

Comment: спасибо, это действительно помогло! :З

Comment: @user195829: если помогло, вы можете принять ответ (галочка справа от вопроса),

Comment: да я жду пока разрешат

Comment: вы очень добры. спасибо

Comment: @user195829: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь при случае.